# Meaning of a derivative in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

So I know that we can find $dy/dx$ of a curve in polar coordinates by leveraging the fact that $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$, and since $r$ is a function of $\theta$ we can take $dy/d\theta$ and $dx/d\theta$ and divide them. But my question is, staying in polar coordinates can we glean anything about the tangent slopes from just $dr/d\theta$? For instance if we have $r=sin\theta$, then $dr/d\theta=cos\theta$. So when $\theta$ is equal to $0$,  $r$ is changing with respect to $\theta$ at a rate of $1$? I can't seem to wrap my head around what this means. Obviously in cartesian coords. the slope of the tangent when $x=0$ is $0$ and infinite when $y=1/2$. Is there no way to intuitively see this from just looking at $dr/d\theta$?

Comment: This might help http://calculus7.com/sitebuildercontent/sitebuilderfiles/calcplrdrvtvs.pdf

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a curve $\gamma$ is given in *polar form*
$$\gamma:\quad r=r(\theta)\qquad(\theta_0\leq\theta\leq \theta_1)$$
this is an abbreviation for the parametric representation
$$\gamma:\quad\theta\mapsto{\bf r}(\theta)=\bigl(r(\theta)\cos\theta, r(\theta)\sin\theta\bigr)\qquad(\theta_0\leq\theta\leq \theta_1)\ .$$
You are asking for the geometric meaning of the derivative $r'(\theta)={dr\over d\theta}$. This can be seen in the following figure. The curve $\gamma$ intersects the concentric circles $r={\rm const.}$ under a varying angle $\alpha$. For a given $\theta$ we have
$$\tan\alpha={dr\over r\,d\theta}={r'(\theta)\over r(\theta)}\ .$$
This shows that $r'(\theta)$ in the first place carries information about this $\alpha$, and not about slopes ${dy\over dx}$, and similar.

When $r'(\theta_0)=0$ for some $\theta_0$ then $\alpha=0$. This means that the circle $r=r(\theta_0)$ and $\gamma$ are touching at the corresponding point $P$, but not that they have the same curvature there. Often it means that the function $\theta\mapsto r(\theta)$ has a local extremum at $\theta_0$, hence $P$ could be the point on $\gamma$ which is nearest or farthest from the origin.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is just what I was looking for. So am I right in thinking then that if $dr/d\theta = 0$ for some $\theta$ then $\gamma$ is "coincident" with some circle $r=const.$?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dy}{dx}$ is, by definition, the limit of a secant line as the distance between two points approaches zero - it simply is the slope, nothing more to prove really (other than that the derivative actually exists, which is beyond the scope of this question).

Also, $tan(θ)=\frac{opposite}{adjacent}$ for right triangles; since we define slope as $\frac{Δy}{Δx}$ and this is basically what the derivative gives you: a small change in y over a small change in x. We can find the inclination $θ$ by taking the arctangent of both sides.

However, in polar coordinate system, there is a pole (analogous to origin in Cartesian coordinate system) and a polar axis as reference direction (analogous to $+ve$ $x$-axis in Cartesian coordinate system) but there is no analogy for $y$-axis. However, to define the slope of tangent, as mentioned above, we need the distances of the point from two fixed perpendicular oriented lines.

So, in order to tackle this we convert the polar coordinates $(r, \theta) $ to Cartesian ones $(x, y) $ as $$x=rcos\;\theta \text{and} y=rsin\;\theta$$. We can get the slope as $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{d\theta}}{\frac{dx}{d\theta}}$$.

Now, your doubt regarding $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$. Well, it just implies the rate of change of distance of the point from the pole w.r.t. to the polar angle. It has nothing to do with the slope of tangent. The Cartesian coordinate system is defined in such a way that the slope of tangent directly comes out to be $\frac{dy}{dx}$ (as $dy$ and $dx$ itself represent the opposite and adjacent side required for slope) but not $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$ in polar coordinate system.